# How to output "Home" instead "my site name" in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show "Home" text only for my wordpress breadcrumb with `$home = get_bloginfo('name');` part function, but it gives me output like this: "my site name". How can I replace "my site name" to "Home"?

Comment: If it's always "Home" why not just set `$home = "Home"`?

Comment: i did it so $home = 'Home';

Comment: Hi, I've checked your previous questions and I'd **strongly suggest** that you head up to the **[help]**, specially the section *Asking*. Also check the additional resources linked in the guide [ask]. I think you may be dangerously close to a question ban.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,i'm new here,i'll care about my questions in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong function to get home url in your home text.

```
get_bloginfo('name');
```

get_bloginfo 'name' - Returns the "Site Title" set in Settings > General. This data is retrieved from the "blogname" record in the wp_options table.

Possible solution:

Use below code to get home/site url to show in breadcrumb

```
$url = home_url('/');
echo "<a href=$url> Home </a>";
```

Above code is tested in `header.php`.

Read further about official wordpress useful functions: 
[`home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) and [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)

Use below code in `function.php`:

```
function bloglow_get_breadcrumb_navigation() {
    $delimiter = '&raquo;';
    $home =  "Home"; // get_bloginfo('name');
    $before = '<span>';
    $after = '</span>';
    echo '<div id="breadcrumb"><!-- Bloglow breadcrumb navigation without a plugin v1.0 - http://bloglow.com/plugins/display-wordpress-breadcrumb-navigation-without-a-plugin/ -->';
    global $post;
    $homeLink = get_bloginfo('url');
    echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '">' . $home . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
    if ( is_category() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thisCat = $cat_obj->term_id;
        $thisCat = get_category($thisCat);
        $parentCat = get_category($thisCat->parent);
        if ($thisCat->parent != 0) echo(get_category_parents($parentCat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' '));
        echo $before . 'Archive by category "' . single_cat_title('', false) . '"' . $after;
    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
        echo '<a href="' . get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')) . '">' . get_the_time('F') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
        echo $before . 'Archive by date "' . get_the_time('d') . '"' . $after;
    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')) . '">' . get_the_time('Y') . '</a> ' . $delimiter . ' ';
        echo $before . 'Archive by month "' . get_the_time('F') . '"' . $after;
    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
        echo $before . 'Archive by year "' . get_the_time('Y') . '"' . $after;
    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
        if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
            $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
            $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
            echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>' . $delimiter . ' ';
            echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        } else {
            $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
            echo ' ' . get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ') . ' ';
            echo $before . 'You&apos;re currently reading "' . get_the_title() . '"' . $after;
        }
        } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
            $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
            echo $before . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $after;
        } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
            $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
            $breadcrumbs = array();
            while ($parent_id) {
                $page = get_page($parent_id);
                $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
                $parent_id    = $page->post_parent;
            }
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
            foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo ' ' . $crumb . ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
            echo $before . 'You&apos;re currently viewing "' . get_the_title() . '"' . $after;
        } elseif ( is_page() && !$post->post_parent ) {
            echo $before . 'You&apos;re currently reading "' . get_the_title() . '"' . $after;
        } elseif ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
            $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
            $breadcrumbs = array();
            while ($parent_id) {
                $page = get_page($parent_id);
                $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a>';
                $parent_id    = $page->post_parent;
            }
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
            foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo ' ' . $crumb . ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
            echo $before . 'You&apos;re currently reading "' . get_the_title() . '"' . $after;
        } elseif ( is_search() ) {
            echo $before . 'Search results for "' . get_search_query() . '"' . $after;
        } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
            echo $before . 'Archive by tag "' . single_tag_title('', false) . '"' . $after;
        } elseif ( is_author() ) {
            global $author;
            $userdata = get_userdata($author);
            echo $before . 'Articles posted by "' . $userdata->display_name . '"' . $after;
        } elseif ( is_404() ) {
            echo $before . 'You got it "' . 'Error 404 not Found' . '"&nbsp;' . $after;
        }
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
            echo ('Page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
            if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
        }
        echo '</div><!-- / Bloglow breadcrumb navigation without a plugin -->';
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to edit this author's function http://bloglow.com/tutorials/display-wordpress-breadcrumb-navigation-without-a-plugin/

Comment: @user3721912
Try
$home =  "Home"; // get_bloginfo('name');
inside
function bloglow_get_breadcrumb_navigation()

Comment: was my estimation(replay @tomaroo) true? thank you now i'm releaved

Comment: BTW im' using custom blog page and when i visit blog page this function shows "Home >>" but i want it to show like this "Home >> Blog"

Comment: just tried on blog page at my local wordpress installation and it output like 
Home » You're currently reading "blog"

Secondly use following custom breadcrumb code
[link] http://cazue.com/articles/wordpress-creating-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin-2013 [/link]

Comment: Secondly use this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/installation/
after installation use this code in your files to call breadcrumb
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
    {
        bcn_display();
    }?>
</div>
Also please mark up on my answer if you think i really helped.

Comment: unfortunately i can not mark up because i dont have 15 reputation,but i've accepted it as right answer.Thank you!